# Solve the partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Write down a general formula for the general solution $$u_t + u_x + 3u =0$$
 where $3u$ governs the rate of decay. I am having a little difficulty solving this to find the general solution. any idea that will be great

Answer (score 0):

let the solution is
$$u=X.T$$
where 
$X=f(x)$ and $T=g(t)$
so 
$$u_t=XT'$$
$$u_x=X'T$$
institute in the equation
$$XT'+X'T+3XT=0$$
divide by $XT$
$$\frac{T'}{T}+\frac{X'}{X}+3=0$$
now let
$$\frac{T'}{T}=\lambda$$ 
or 
$$\frac{T'}{T}=-\lambda$$ 
 sign of $\lambda$ depends on the problem

anyhow, I will take the positive to write the solution
$$T=C_1e^{\lambda t}$$
the second equation is
$$\lambda+\frac{X'}{X}+3=0$$
or $$\frac{X'}{X}=-3-\lambda$$
the solution is
$$X=C_2e^{(-3-\lambda)x}$$
so the solution of $u$ is
$$u=C_1e^{\lambda t}.C_2e^{(-3-\lambda)x}$$
$$u=k_1e^{\lambda t-\lambda x-3}$$
use the boundary conditions to know the value of $\lambda$